# Building JSON from other method calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a helper class that builds me some JSON structures I need for RSpec testing. For example it has methods like this:

```
  def self.create_value_tooltip_hash
    {
      tooltip_value: 'high',
      tooltip_type: 'payer_amount'
    }
  end


  def self.create_value_hash
    {
      value: '3400',
      type: 'payer'
    }
  end
```

Now I have a bigger JSON that actually contains many elements from the same smaller JSONs that I have written method for them above.
So is there a way to take advantage of those methods and construct my bigger JSON by calling those smaller methods?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.create_value_tooltip_hash.merge(Object.create_value_hash)
```